# Call a web method using jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, autocomplete, webmethod

I want to create an `Autocomplete` field for a search option. I have tried with following code.

But **the web method doesn't fire** when the `Autocomplete` function is execution.
What will be the reason ?

Here is the jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
         source:function (request, response) {
         $.ajax ({
             type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "~/Services/AutoComplete.asmx/GetFarmersByName",
            data: "{ 'name' : '" + $("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                      response($(data.d, function (item) {
                                return            {
                                    value: item.AdrNm
                                }
                       }));
                     },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });
 </script>
```

Here is the web method

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result> GetFarmersByName(string name)
    {
        this._personalData = new personalData();
        int cky = 45;
        CdMa cdMas = new CdMa();
        cdMas = this._personalData.getcdMasByConcdCd2(cky, "AdrPreFix", true);
        int prefixKy = cdMas.CdKy;

        List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result> list = new List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result>();

        list = this._personalData.GetPersonalDataByName(prefixKy, cky, name);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Try including using this attribute `[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`

Comment: Your debugger reach at `AutoComplete.asmx` ??

Comment: Above your service class add [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: I think web methods need to be Static?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you hit the webservice function by having breakpoint on your service function. Please change your script to below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").autocomplete
        ({

            source:
            function (request, response) {
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: " <%=ResolveUrl("~/Services/AutoComplete.asmx/GetFarmersByName") %>",

                    data: "{ 'name' : '" + $("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",

                    dataType: "json",

                    type: "POST",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                   

                    async: true,

                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },

                    success: function (data) 
                    {
                        response($(data.d, function (item) 
                        {
                            return
                            {
                                value: item.AdrNm
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried with your code. But still web method doesn't hit.

Answer (score 2):

Above your service class add  `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Or you can do this in  an asp.net page!

add the static keyword and change the webservice to ASP.NET page!

```
 public static string GetFarmersByName(string name)
```

For example:

A.aspx:

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "A.aspx/GetSN",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async:false,
                    success: function (json) {
                        var msg = JSON.parse(json.d);
                        sn = msg;
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("Sorry,there is a error!");
                    }
                });
```

Then in your A.aspx.cs type in:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetSN()
        {
            Random RN = new Random();
            string year = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy").ToString();
            string MonAndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd").ToString();
            string Hour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHMMss").ToString() + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + RN.Next(100, 900).ToString();
            string SerialNumber = year + MonAndDate + Hour;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SerialNumber);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried your code. But web method doesn't hit.

Comment: In my projects there is no problem.If you do that in asp.net page the GetFarmersByName method canot return List.you can just retun json string .So change 'List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result>' to string

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `tags` as your textbox,  set data as `{ 'name': '" + request.term + "'}`

```
$("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "Services/AutoComplete.asmx/GetFarmersByName",
             data: "{ 'name': '" + request.term + "'}",
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {
                 response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                     return {
                         label: item.split('-')[0],
                         val: item.split('-')[1]
                     }
                 }))
             },
             error: function (response) {
                 alert(response.responseText);
             },
             failure: function (response) {
                 alert(response.responseText);
             },
         });
     },
     minLength: 0,
     focus: function () {
         // prevent value inserted on focus
         return false;
     },
 });
```

debug on method GetFarmersByName,

**NOTE:** Check have you uncomment `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` on .asmx page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Still i having the same problem. I've put  breakpoints to the web method. but it doesn't hit.

Comment: have you added `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in ur asmx.cs

Answer (score 1):

Post again!!!

Test.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#Button1").bind("click",function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Test.asmx/GetFarmersByName",
                    data:"{'aaa':'zhangsan'}",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (json) {

                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("Sorry,there is a error!");
                    }
                });
            })
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.asmx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestWebForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Test
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Test : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<string> GetFarmersByName(string aaa)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(aaa);
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP have clearly mention that webmethod is not hit, i.e he doesnt hit .asmx page, der might be client side prblm while call .ajac or JQuery Library missing, Also its not on button click as u use in ur code, Its **JQuery Autocomplete**

Answer (score 1):

Paste this method inside code behind file where you are calling this method. Change url to url: "Test.aspx/GetFarmersByName" and then test it. Its much clean code rather then Web Service.

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetFarmersByName(string aaa)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(aaa);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { $("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
     source:function (request, response) {
     var obj = JSON.Stringfy("{ 'name' : '" + $("#<%=tags.ClientID %>").val() + "'}");
     $.ajax ({
         type: "POST",
        url: "~/Services/AutoComplete.asmx/GetFarmersByName",
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
        success: function (data) {
                  response($(data.d, function (item) {
                            return            {
                                value: item.AdrNm
                            }
                   }));
                 },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
```

and the webmethod-

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result> GetFarmersByName(string name)
{
    this._personalData = new personalData();
    int cky = 45;
    CdMa cdMas = new CdMa();
    cdMas = this._personalData.getcdMasByConcdCd2(cky, "AdrPreFix", true);
    int prefixKy = cdMas.CdKy;

    List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result> list = new List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result>();

    list = this._personalData.GetPersonalDataByName(prefixKy, cky, name);
    return list;
}
```