# Without Response.End() code does't works fine

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

i am using jquery ajax function ,i  recieve the data in success function if place Response.End() at server side i didnot understand what is the reason behind this????

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "WebForm1.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                alert(reuslt.CustomerID);

            }
        });
    });
```

In WebForm1.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.CustomerID = "1";
            c.ContactName = "Jhon";
            c.CompanyName = "Dell";
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String response = serializer.Serialize(c);
            Response.Write(response);
            Response.End();

          }
```

Customer Class

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629(v=vs.90).aspx I'm not a C# developer, but chances are that prevents some other piece of code from outputting something that makes your json invalid. It immediately aborts the request and returns what has been generated thus far to the browser.

Comment: Open the Dev Tools Network tab and look at what the server is sending you.

Comment: You should really use a HTTP handler for this rather than the full overhead of a Page.

Comment: i simply want to receive json result from server ,i have read many tutorials that is almost the same but not working in my scenario why Response.End works fine otherwise  error.

Comment: @Ali my comment explains why it fixes the problem, and most of the answers explain that as well and how to fix it. What part of these answers are you having trouble with?

Comment: i have verifed the json that server is returning but point to focus why code doesn't works fine with Response.End()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a Webmethod, which means de .aspx file still gives response of the HTML. The `Response.end()` ends the response, which means no further code is executed.

What you need to do is:

In the VB file:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse=false)]
public Customer getCustomer()
{
   //implementation code
   return new Customer(); // The code you need
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/getCustomer", // Webmethod function here
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: function (json) {
                    var msg = JSON.parse(json.d);
                    alert(msg.customerID);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("Sorry,there is a error!");
                }
            });
```

Information:

1. [Webmethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
2. [jQuery ICM webmethod call (stackoverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463205/call-a-web-method-using-jquery-ajax)
3. More info can be found by search `jQuery c# Webmethod` on Google.

**UDPATE**
Because Ali want's to specific know why with `response.end` and without that it fails. Because with `response.end` will end the request. So no furter code is executed. Which means the HTML is not rendered. Without this code the HTML is rendered and also reponded as the response. Which means the JSON + HTML are the output of the request.

> Sends all currently buffered output to the client, stops execution of
>   the page, and raises the EndRequest event.

Since [`Response.end`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) throws an exception as quoted from the documentation (above). It is better to use [`HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i donot want to use web Method i simply want to know that why Response.End() makes my code working fine

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact output off hand, but the idea is that you web forms (.aspx) use a page lifecycle.  If you don't end the lifecycle by calling `Response.End()`, the page will continue processing and emitting to the output stream.

Thus, it will eventually reach its render stage and write out the contents of the .asxp file if you don't tell ASP.NET to stop outputting to the response stream.

Try using Fiddler to view the resulting response/html if you don't call `Response.End()` to see what is returned.

(And also what @Niels said-- my answer is more for a non-ajax implementation)

Comment: but how to solve my problem without using web method and Response.End()

Comment: web forms doesn't work that way.  You'd have to either use `[WebMethod()]`, create a web service, or create pages that would send back the response you are looking for.  Handlers wired to a specific url may also work for you, but those solutions aren't very great for clarity.  It seems like your main concern may be the lack of sessionstate access?

Comment: Or you could use the UpdatePanel controls to do the ajax for you.  This is easily done, but it adds a ton of overhead in terms of required bandwidth on both ends.