# Calling vb code-behind function from ajax-call

Tags: ajax, vb.net, code-behind

I try to call a shared vb function from markup with ajax-call but it doesn't return the string, it returns the markup of the whole page.

ajax-call from button #apply in file philipp.aspx

```
jQuery("#apply").click(function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "philipp.aspx/Test",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data + " Successful")
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.status + " Not Successful")
                    }
                });
            });
```

vb code-behind in philipp.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

<ScriptService()>
Partial Public Class PhilippPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    End Sub

    <WebMethod()>
    Private Shared Function Test() As String
        Dim msg As String = "Horray"

        Return msg
    End Function
End Class
```

the success function of the ajax-call is being executed...

Comment: The normal way would be to add a web service (asmx) file to the project instead of using an aspx page for that. Then it will only return what you want instead of the page headers/markup/etc.

Comment: We have an older implementation for a client that is similar to this (didn't code it myself, so merely sharing what is there)..... In the AJAX success function, we check ````data.d```` to get the return value (it's a boolean return value, not string), not just data. This also uses the code-behind WebMethod as opposed to the .asmx implementation.

Comment: Similar issue on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463205/call-a-web-method-using-jquery-ajax